# Azure Logic App Standard - Some of the connections are not authorized yet

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-app-service-envrmnt, azure-logic-app-standard

I'm creating a logic apps standard workflow hosted in an ase v3. I have the built-in file system connector to collect from an on-prem file share. I was able to create the workflow in the azure portal. However, when I return to it and click save I get the following message:

> Some of the connections are not authorized yet. If you just created a
> workflow from a template, please add the authorized connections to
> your workflow before saving

The code for the workflow is shown below:

```json
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Copy_file": {
                "inputs": {
                    "parameters": {
                        "destination": "destination_path_here",
                        "source": "@triggerOutputs()?['body']?['path']"
                    },
                    "serviceProviderConfiguration": {
                        "connectionName": "FileSystem",
                        "operationId": "copyFile",
                        "serviceProviderId": "/serviceProviders/FileSystem"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ServiceProvider"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "triggers": {
            "When_a_file_is_added": {
                "conditions": [
                    {
                        "expression": "@not(equals(triggerBody().Size,0))"
                    }
                ],
                "inputs": {
                    "parameters": {
                        "folderPath": "source_path_here"
                    },
                    "serviceProviderConfiguration": {
                        "connectionName": "FileSystem",
                        "operationId": "whenFilesAreAdded",
                        "serviceProviderId": "/serviceProviders/FileSystem"
                    }
                },
                "kind": "Polling",
                "recurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Second",
                    "interval": 15
                },
                "splitOn": "@triggerOutputs()?['body']",
                "type": "ServiceProvider"
            }
        }
    },
    "kind": "Stateful"
}
```

Comment: Could you please share designer flow image?